# Callback function returning false CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, callback

Why is this my code returning false in my if condition at my callback code. I tried to var_dump every each of their values and

Here is the output of the var_dump

```
var_dump($old_password_hash); = string(32) "25d55ad283aa400af464c76d713c07ad"
var_dump($old_password_db_hash); = object(stdClass)#24 (1) { ["user_password"]=> string(32) "25d55ad283aa400af464c76d713c07ad" }
```

The two values doesnt satisfies in  `if($old_password_hash != $old_password_db_hash) {`

Here is my full code

```
public function oldpassword_check($old_password){
    $id = $this->input->post('userid');

    $old_password_hash = md5($old_password);
    $old_password_db_hash = $this->prof_model->fetch_pwrod($id);

    //var_dump($old_password_hash);

    var_dump($old_password_db_hash);

    if($old_password_hash != $old_password_db_hash) {

        $this->form_validation->set_message('oldpassword_check', 'Old password not match');
        return FALSE;

    } else {

        return TRUE;

    } 

}
```

Comment: I hope you are not using md5 for anything that requires security

Comment: Use this for password hashing http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php and this for password verify http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php Your md5 is insecure now days not recommended for passwords

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$old_password_hash` is a **string**

`$old_password_db_hash` is an **object**

They will **never** be equal. `string` **never** equals `object`.

That's why `$old_password_hash != $old_password_db_hash` is always **true**. And therefore `FALSE` is returned.

Proper check is:

```
// take `user_password` property of an object
if ($old_password_hash != $old_password_db_hash->user_password) {
  $this->form_validation->set_message('oldpassword_check', 'Old password not match');
  return FALSE;
}
else {
  return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: can you explain to me sir. how did you make the object into a string ?

Comment: I didn't. Instead I take a __property__ of an object. And property (`user_password`) has type string too.